# Import .aspx page to Sharepoint with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I'm trying to import an .aspx page to sharepoint with powershell scripts, I've tried a few ways and some work, however I don't understand why when I run the script and previously specified that only one file is imported, the output is that all the files in the folder were imported.

This is my code:

```
$Site = "http://11.11.1.100:10000/"
Import-SPWeb –identity $Site -path "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pages\page1.aspx" -force
```

In the folder I have:

- page1.aspx
- page2.aspx
- page3.aspx

As I said before I execute the script and the output is that all the files in the folder were imported.

The log:

```
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] Progress: Initializing Import.
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] Warning: Export only contains the last major of a file.
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] Progress: Starting content import.
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] Progress: De-Serializing Objects to Database.
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Paginas] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Paginas]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Forms] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Forms]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Carpeta] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Carpeta]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Carpeta
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Página
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página de artículo] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página de artículo]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Página de artículo
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página de error] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página de error]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Página de error
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página principal] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [Folder] [Página principal]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Página principal
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [AllItems.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [AllItems.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/AllItems.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [AllItems.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/AllItems.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [AllItems.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Combine.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Combine.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Combine.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Combine.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/Combine.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Combine.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [DispForm.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [DispForm.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/DispForm.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [DispForm.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/DispForm.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [DispForm.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [EditForm.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [EditForm.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/EditForm.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [EditForm.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/EditForm.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [EditForm.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [repair.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [repair.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/repair.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [repair.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/repair.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [repair.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Thumbnails.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Thumbnails.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Thumbnails.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/Thumbnails.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Thumbnails.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Upload.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Upload.aspx]   Verbose: Source URL: Paginas/Forms/Upload.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Upload.aspx]   Verbose: Destination URL: /Paginas/Forms/Upload.aspx
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [File] [Upload.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [List] [Páginas] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [default.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [default.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [default.aspx]   Progress: Importing web parts
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [default.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [default.aspx]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [PageNotFoundError.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:44] [ListItem] [PageNotFoundError.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [PageNotFoundError.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [PageNotFoundError.aspx]     Verbose: Import 2 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page1.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page1.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page1.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page1.aspx]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page2.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page2.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page2.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page2.aspx]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page3.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page3.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page3.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [page3.aspx]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [pagetest.aspx] Progress: Importing
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [pagetest.aspx]   Verbose: List URL: /Paginas
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [pagetest.aspx]   Progress: Importing Links
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] [ListItem] [pagetest.aspx]     Verbose: Import 1 server-relative links.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Verbose: Performing final fixups.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Progress: Import completed.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Finish Time: 05/06/2023 11:42:45.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Duration: 00:00:01
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Total Objects: 28
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Finished with 1 warnings.
[05/06/2023 11:42:45] Finished with 0 errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

ImportSPWeb will copy the whole site, you only want the page - so you're using the cmdlet incorrectly. The easiest way would be to use PnP.PowerShell/SharePointPnPOnline depending on the version of SharePoint you're using. Code is below

```
connect-pnponline -url exampleweb.com/sites/sitetocopyfrom -interactive
get-pnpsitetemplate -out "template.xml" -IncludeAllPages -handlers pages
connect-pnponline -url exampleweb.com/sites/newsite -interactive
invoke-pnpsitetemplate -clearnavigation -path .\template.xml
```

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPSiteTemplate.html
https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Invoke-PnPSiteTemplate.html